# could not create yii2 project with composer

Tags: ubuntu, yii2, composer-php, lamp

I am trying to create a yii2 project with the composer and getting this error

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

error:
https://pastebin.com/XgSt9Z2B

```
  root@xuf-SATELLITE-C50t-A:/var/www/html/suppare# composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic suppare
    Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
    Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-basic (2.0.14)
      - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-basic (2.0.14): Loading from cache
    Created project in suppare
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


  Problem 1
    - codeception/phpunit-wrapper 6.0.2 requires sebastian/diff ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[3.0.0].
    - codeception/phpunit-wrapper 7.0.0 requires sebastian/diff ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[3.0.0].
    - codeception/phpunit-wrapper 7.0.1 requires sebastian/diff ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[3.0.0].
    - codeception/phpunit-wrapper 7.0.2 requires sebastian/diff ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[3.0.0].
```

i WAS getting missing extension error for php-mbstring prior to the above error so  ran this command and now im getting the above errors. the composer creates incomplete project with error which doesnt show up on the browser
    sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

Comment: can you confirm which php version you are using and which php version is running on cli, and you havent added what command you ran

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam issue resolved, im using php7 btw and the command i ran is in the code above.

Comment: yeah thats what i suspected good to know you solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like phpunit was missing so i ran

```
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

and it fixed the issue